# The Briton could only win the title if Rosberg finished off the podium. What is the meaning of finished off?

Tags: meaning

Here is a quick question. The meaning of:"finish OFF" and more generally the world "OFF" because i know that this is different of the world "OF"

pronunciation which change ?

Comment: Please give full context. Where did this sentence come from (give a link). Is this a sword battle for the king of England on top of a podium? Or is it about a string of tennis matches? Or something else?

Comment: However, in other contexts, *finish off* can mean *eat* or *destroy*. Or, in a narrow meaning, bring to sexual satisfaction. None of those things would normally apply to a podium …

Comment: @Mitch The context is clear if you follow Formula 1 motor racing even to the limited extent that I do. Nico Rosberg and his father Keke were well known racing drivers and finishing in the first three places in a race is referred to as a "podium finish" or "finishing on the podium". Since the championship is decided by the total number of points won in the season the Briton (probably Lewis Hamilton) could only win the championship if Rosberg finished lower than third in the final race. This must be non-current quote since Nico Rosberg retired in 2016.

Comment: @BoldBen And lotsa other sports and contests. I love the image of a contestant chewing up the podium chunk by chunk, paper skirt and all.

Comment: In other words, "off" in this sentence simply means "not on". Welcome to EL&U, by the way! Take the [tour] if you haven't yet. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

This means that the Briton only has a chance of winning the title if Rosberg's finishing metric is unworthy of 3rd place or above (assuming a three-spot podium as is standard).

The term "off" in this instance signifies the *opposite* of being atop the podium.

Comment: Yes...to elaborate a bit, the phrase in question is *not* "finish off" but rather "off the podium". That is to say, the word "off" *begins* a prepositional phrase instead of completing a phrasal verb.

Comment: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/fr/dictionnaire/anglais/finish-sth-off

Comment: @Alexandrelenard - it is not that meaning.  Instead it is finishing in a position that did not put him *on* the podium